# Rails : why data doesn't get submitted when a custom name attribute is added to the text_field?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5, formvalidation.io

The data doesn't get submitted when the name attribute is added in the text_field, When i remove the name attribute it gets submitted fine but the jquery validation doesn't work. I am using jquery formvalidation.io plugin for validation, i want to add a custom name attribute in text_field in order to validate. so far i am finding it difficult to follow, I tried adding like this " 'name'=>'test' " in text_field but no use, hope someone will come up with a solution so that both jquery validation and data submission works fine, thanks.

This is my HTML

```
<section class="content">
    <%= form_for(tbl_ad_test_overview, :html => {:class => "form-online", :id => "form", :style => "margin-left: 15px; width: 95%;"}) do |f|%>

            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :test, 'Test Number *', class: 'font-color' %>
                <%= f.text_field :test, id: 'test', name:'test', placeholder: 'Test Number', class: 'form-control'%>
                <br>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-offset-5">
                    <%= f.submit "Submit", id: 'validate', class: 'btn btn-primary'%>
                </div>
            </div>
    <% end %>
</section>
```

This is my Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
 $('#validate').on('click', function(event) {   
  $('#form').formValidation({
    framework : 'bootstrap',
    icon : {
        valid : 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid : 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating : 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields : {
        test : {
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message : 'Please enter a positive number greater than 0'
                },
                stringLength : {
                    min : 1,
                    message : 'Please do enter at least 1 number'
                },
             }
           }
        }
     });
  });   
});
```

This is required params in controller

```
def tbl_ad_test_overview_params
    params.require(:tbl_ad_test_overview).permit(:test)  
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text_field(:post, :title, size: 20)`

`# => <input type="text" id="post_title" name="post[title]" size="20" value="#{@post.title}" />`

`form helpers` generates *default names* with the help of `form_for` record and adding a custom name to the form helpers **overrides** the default name.

You are overriding the default name(in your case it will be **`tbl_ad_test_overview[test]`**) to `test` which **would have lead to failed submission**.

***Solution:***

**Don't add a custom name**, instead use the default name in Jquery validation.

```
<%= f.text_field :test, id: 'test', placeholder: 'Test Number', class: 'form-control'%>
```

and use `"tbl_ad_test_overview[test]"` instead of `test` in Jquery validation.

Comment: thanks for approaching,  I tried what u told but now the validation is not working now .

Comment: @SagarRS did you changed the field name to `tbl_ad_test_overview[test]`?

Comment: <%= f.text_field :test, id: 'test', name:'tbl_ad_test_overview[:test]', placeholder: 'Test Number', class: 'form-control'%>
IN JQUERY ( tbl_ad_test_overview[:test] : {........} )

Comment: @SagarRS No, keep the `text_field` like this `<%= f.text_field :test, id: 'test', placeholder: 'Test Number', class: 'form-control'%>` and use `tbl_ad_test_overview[test]` in validation

Comment: hey @Pavan i tried it and its trying to submit without validation, I had tried this before asking the question in stack overflow .

Comment: @SagarRS You mean with wrong input, the form is submitting without validation?

Comment: @SagarRS Just inspect the text_field in console and paste the HTML snippet here.

Comment: in console this is the error showing up  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [  "  coz of this  tbl_ad_test_overview[test] in jquery .

Comment: @SagarRS Ok Try this `"tbl_ad_test_overview[test]"` please

Comment: @SagarRS Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first write the validation script in the proper way like with the use of the below example code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loginForm').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            username: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The username is required'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The username must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                        message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                    }
                }
            },
            password: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The password is required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Make your code with use the format something similar to the above format. If you are having the problem with the custom name then please write the script and make the form submit with the name which parsed by the embedded script. From my point of view updating, the name should not affect the form properties.

Comment: Yes, I have read it out. And according to your answer why can't we add the validations on custom name of inputs.

Comment: No, You didn't read the question! We can write the validations for custom names, but the OP problem is the form is not submitted when he added custom attribute. And tell what format you are talking about here?

Comment: @Bharatsoni thank you for the approach , Pavan i right .

Comment: @Pavan There are some misleading semicolumns for the format of the validation like 'validators :', that should be proper as per the plugin. We can't see any visual screen of the questioner but we can assume and can give the answer. But this not about you can't add the custom name of the attributes.